# APP crashed when I installed the RN update

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-code-push

I integrate react-native-code-push to my RN project. But when I installed the update, the APP was crashed. [Here](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1GszoGapZB_I1Y3CRZtYpXA) is the source code.

```
2018-10-30 11:26:52.274 14122-14122/com.example.jason.rnandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jason.rnandroid, PID: 14122
java.lang.AssertionError: recreateReactContextInBackground should only be called after the initial createReactContextInBackground call.
    at com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertCondition(Assertions.java:72)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:339)
    at com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePushNativeModule$2.run(CodePushNativeModule.java:151)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, can anyone help?